# rpy2 error after installing r package

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I am trying to use the r package called "huge". I am having a problem in rpy2 in that I am trying to install this package, which the code runs fine using the following code:

```
import rpy2.robjects.packages as rpackages

# import R's utility package
utils = rpackages.importr('utils')

# select a mirror for R packages
utils.chooseCRANmirror(ind=1) # select the first mirror in the list

packnames = ('huge')

# R vector of strings
from rpy2.robjects.vectors import StrVector

# Selectively install what needs to be install.
# We are fancy, just because we can.
names_to_install = ['huge']
if len(names_to_install) > 0:
    utils.install_packages(StrVector(names_to_install))
```

With only warnings, telling me that:

```
/home/johnzhou/anaconda3/envs/python35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:145: RRuntimeWarning: also installing the dependency ‘igraph’


  warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)
/home/johnzhou/anaconda3/envs/python35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:145: RRuntimeWarning: trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/igraph_1.1.2.tar.gz'

  warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)
/home/johnzhou/anaconda3/envs/python35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:145: RRuntimeWarning: Content type 'application/x-gzip'
  warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)
/home/johnzhou/anaconda3/envs/python35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:145: RRuntimeWarning:  length 3376958 bytes (3.2 MB)

  warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)
/home/johnzhou/anaconda3/envs/python35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:145: RRuntimeWarning: =
  warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)
/home/johnzhou/anaconda3/envs/python35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:145: RRuntimeWarning: 

  warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)
/home/johnzhou/anaconda3/envs/python35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:145: RRuntimeWarning: downloaded 3.2 MB


  warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)
/home/johnzhou/anaconda3/envs/python35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:145: RRuntimeWarning: trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/huge_1.2.7.tar.gz'

  warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)
/home/johnzhou/anaconda3/envs/python35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:145: RRuntimeWarning:  length 2946819 bytes (2.8 MB)

  warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)
/home/johnzhou/anaconda3/envs/python35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:145: RRuntimeWarning: downloaded 2.8 MB


  warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)
/home/johnzhou/anaconda3/envs/python35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:145: RRuntimeWarning: 
  warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)
/home/johnzhou/anaconda3/envs/python35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:145: RRuntimeWarning: The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpOb6GhL/downloaded_packages’
  warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)
/home/johnzhou/anaconda3/envs/python35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:145: RRuntimeWarning: Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'

  warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)
/home/johnzhou/anaconda3/envs/python35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:145: RRuntimeWarning: Making 'packages.html' ...
  warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)
/home/johnzhou/anaconda3/envs/python35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:145: RRuntimeWarning:  done

  warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)
```

However, when I try to load the package using:

```
rpy2.robjects.packages.importr("huge")
```

I get an error message where it tells me that:

```
RRuntimeError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-104-843fb8da3355> in <module>()
----> 1 rpy2.robjects.packages.importr("huge")

~/anaconda3/envs/python35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/packages.py in importr(name, lib_loc, robject_translations, signature_translation, suppress_messages, on_conflict, symbol_r2python, symbol_check_after, data)
    451     if _package_has_namespace(rname, 
    452                               _system_file(package = rname)):
--> 453         env = _get_namespace(rname)
    454         version = _get_namespace_version(rname)[0]
    455         exported_names = set(_get_namespace_exports(rname))

RRuntimeError: Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘huge’
```

Could someone help me with this please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to check the library where your package is being installed?

I had the same issue few days ago and I followed these steps
1. check library paths using .libPaths() in R
2. Try installing the packages in R console using install.packages('package name')
3. Check to see the package is installed in the paths you got as a result of step 1 mentioned above.
4. if its installed in different library then just do a simple copy of packages from that directory to the .libPaths() libraries.

R tries to look for libraries in default location and you just need to put the packages in the default library path (find it using .libPaths())

hope it helps